# Can I color the first bar in "Bart Char" differently?

Tags: chart.js

[View the example](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/6283375/6712720/5d17391a-cd8e-11e4-9bb1-4fb940c51c26.png)

I would like to give a different color for "Your score". I tried doing 2 datasets: one including only the score, second one with other ones, but it didn't work.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the standard chart.js library and just with one dataset.

Just create your chart using **new Chart()** and passing the returned object to a variable, then change whatever properties you wish to display differently, and use the **update()** method to refresh the chart.

Something like this will do :

```js
var myBarChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d")).Bar(ChartData, ChartOptions);

// Change 1st bar (bars[0]) to red (display).
myBarChart.datasets[0].bars[0].fillColor = "rgba(255,0,0,0.7)";
myBarChart.datasets[0].bars[0].strokeColor = "rgba(255,0,0,1)";
// Change 1rd bar to red (highlight setting on mouse over)
myBarChart.datasets[0].bars[0].highlightFill = "rgba(212,10,10,0.7)";
myBarChart.datasets[0].bars[0].highlightStroke = "rgba(212,10,10,1)";

myBarChart.update();
```

See a [jsFiddle DEMO of this here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdtome/pofxr0dp/).

See the [documentation regarding available methods here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-prototype-methods).

Answer (score 0):

I've created a fork of chart js (https://github.com/leighquince/Chart.js) which has an option that can be passed to bar charts to overlay the bars, called `overlayBars`. You could use this feature and define two data sets, one with the the "your score" and the other with all the others.

```js
var overlayData = {
    labels: ["Your Score", "February", "March", "April", "May", "Jun", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My Firstdataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(121,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(121,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(121,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(121,187,205,1)",
        data: [44, null, null, null, null, null, null]
    }, {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(131,137,235,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(131,137,235,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(131,137,235,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(131,137,235,1)",
        data: [null, 23, 66, 33, 55, 44, 101]
    }]
};



var myBarChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Bar(overlayData, {

    overlayBars: true,


});
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/leighquince/Chart.js/master/Chart.js"></script>
<div style="width:30%">
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" height="250" width="400"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

fiddle (http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/x7d1u38L/)